# Update Urls (iframe) in database with REGEXP to new path

Tags: sql, regex, replace

So i need a update urls in my database.

I have a 'forums_post' table nad 'post' column. I would like to replace all links with a new path.

Current path:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://mik.com/my-topic-title-test-t32/?tab=comments&amp;do=embed&amp;comment=438&amp;embedComment=438&amp;embedDo=findComment#comment-438"></iframe>
```

New path:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://mik.com/topic/my-topic-title-test-32/?tab=comments&amp;do=embed&amp;comment=438&amp;embedComment=438&amp;embedDo=findComment#comment-438"></iframe>
```

The point is to add `/topic/` after `http://mik.com` and remove "`t`" from eg. -`t32/`

Please help ;(

Comment: You might want to post the database details if you need help writing the sql query. And I wonder if storing the "base" url in a separate table might not be a bad idea - that way you only have to update one row and not many?

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(http:\/\/mik\.com)\/([A-Za-z-]+?)([a-z])(\d+)\/`

and replace with : `\1/topic/\2\4/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X2e2jb/1)